# Why does add_index using 'gin' create a 'btree' index instead?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, indexing

I am on `PostgreSQL 9.3.4` and `Rails 4.0.4`.

I add a "tags" column, and corresponding `gin` index (or, at least I ask for one).

```
class AddTagsToPhotos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :photos, :tags, :text, array: true, null: false, default: []
    add_index :photos, :tags, using: 'gin'
  end
end
```

Verify the results via `psql`:

```
psql=# \d photos
...
tags  | text[]  | not null default '{}'::text[]
Indexes:
    "index_photos_on_tags" btree (tags)
```

Notice that the "tags" index is of type `btree` - whereas I asked for `gin`.

Now manually create an index to show that `gin` is available:

```
psql=# create index index_photos_on_tags2 on photos using gin(tags) ;

psql=# \d photos
Indexes:
    "index_photos_on_tags" btree (tags)
    "index_photos_on_tags2" gin (tags)
```

Indeed, `gin` is available.

For the time being I am using this **workaround** with raw SQL, but would like to know why the typical approach above is failing:

```
class AddTagsToPhotos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :photos, :tags, :text, array: true, null: false, default: []
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('create index index_photos_on_tags on photos using gin(tags) ;')
  end
  def down
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('drop index index_photos_on_tags')
    remove_column :photos, :tags
  end
end
```

**Note that there is another snag!**

It turns out that `db/schema.rb` will not have `gin` set as the index type:

```
add_index "photos", ["tags"], :name => "index_photos_on_tags"
```

Potential interim workaround:

```
add_index "photos", ["tags"], :name => "index_photos_on_tags", using: :gin
```

**Alert!**

Until this bug is fixed, you must review changes to `db/schema.rb` whenever you run a migration, as all future migrations will strip `using: :gin` from the `add_index` line.

Comment: as a workaround you might also want to specify this line in config/application.rb:  config.active_record.schema_format = :sql otherwise this index, as you mentioned, will not be saved to db/schema.rb

Comment: This works correctly in Rails 4.2.0.

Comment: Note that `execute` is defined in ActiveRecord::Migration, so you don't need to specify `ActiveRecord::Base.connection`.

Answer (score 5):

As paxer mentioned, you will need to set your schema format to `:sql` by adding (or changing) this line in your `config/application.rb`:

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

The reason, as explained in the [Rails Migrations guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html), is that a GIN index is specific to Postgres. When you are using database-specific items, `schema.rb` will not be able to recreate them.

Here is a quote from the Rails guide:

> There is however a trade-off: db/schema.rb cannot express database specific items such as triggers, or stored procedures. While in a migration you can execute custom SQL statements, the schema dumper cannot reconstitute those statements from the database. If you are using features like this, then you should set the schema format to :sql.

Once you use the `:sql` format, your schema will now be saved to `structure.sql` instead of `schema.rb`. Both files can live side by side, but only `structure.sql` will be updated and used by the app when your format is set to `:sql`.